# How to erase element from array list of parcelable using one of its values only?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I am using an array list of custom object that I have. Let's consider it an array list of users where each user has for example userid, user name ....etc. Now I need to delete a user based on its id only because when I want to delete the user there is somethings in it changed before so I can't erase it using the user object.The only idea that I have to do that was to loop over all users of the list but this idea doesn't look good to me. So my question is how can I erase user object from an array list of users using the user id without needs to loop over all the users of the list?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: The only idea I have was to loop over the users of the list but this idea appears very silly to me

Comment: My suggestion would be to add an if condition inside your for loop, so that if the userid matches the user object after 3 loops then you don't have to loop the entire list.

Comment: I had this idea but I am looking for a way without using loops

Comment: Why don't you use a Set instead of List and override hashCode and equals method in your custom class based on id variable only. Then on Set object you can simply call remove method and pass the object you want to remove?

Comment: Can you explain your answer more please

Comment: Let me try adding as answer by giving sample codes because comments doesn't preserve code formatting etc.

Comment: @kumar Rajwanshi can I use this way and in the same time sort users based on date of creation?

Comment: For sorting based on date, you can either implement Comparable interface and provide your implementation based upon date, or externally you can use custom Comparator to sort based on date or even any attributes the way you want on... Let me provide you samples for both

Answer (score 1):

This code illustrates everything you wanted. Notice how hashCode, equals and compareTo methods are overridden.

```
package com.pkr.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class User implements Comparable<User> {

    public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    private long userId;
    private String userName;
    private Date createdDate;

    public User(long userId, String userName, Date createdDate) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("userId: %s, userName: %s, createdDate: %s",
                new Object[] { userId, userName, sdf.format(createdDate) });
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof User) {
            return ((User) o).getUserId() == this.getUserId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(userId).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o) {
        return this.getCreatedDate().compareTo(o.getCreatedDate());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<User>();
        userSet.add(new User(1, "Pushpesh", sdf.parse("16-02-2018")));
        userSet.add(new User(2, "Vikrant", sdf.parse("12-02-2018")));
        userSet.add(new User(3, "Abhay", sdf.parse("11-02-2018")));
        userSet.add(new User(4, "Komal", sdf.parse("18-02-2018")));

        userSet.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        // this will remove user with id 2 no matter what his name and
        // createdDate are
        userSet.remove(new User(2, "Vikrant", sdf.parse("12-02-2018")));

        System.out.println("After removing userId 2");
        userSet.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();

        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(userSet);
        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        userList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        Collections.sort(userList); // This will sort based on date

        System.out.println("After sorting");
        userList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Hope this clarifies all you wanted. Let me know if you further have any query.

Upon execution, this code produces following output,

```
userId: 1, userName: Pushpesh, createdDate: 16-02-2018
userId: 2, userName: Vikrant, createdDate: 12-02-2018
userId: 3, userName: Abhay, createdDate: 11-02-2018
userId: 4, userName: Komal, createdDate: 18-02-2018
After removing userId 2
userId: 1, userName: Pushpesh, createdDate: 16-02-2018
userId: 3, userName: Abhay, createdDate: 11-02-2018
userId: 4, userName: Komal, createdDate: 18-02-2018

Before sorting
userId: 1, userName: Pushpesh, createdDate: 16-02-2018
userId: 3, userName: Abhay, createdDate: 11-02-2018
userId: 4, userName: Komal, createdDate: 18-02-2018
After sorting
userId: 3, userName: Abhay, createdDate: 11-02-2018
userId: 1, userName: Pushpesh, createdDate: 16-02-2018
userId: 4, userName: Komal, createdDate: 18-02-2018
```

Comment: Also if you want your entries to remain sorted automatically, use TreeSet instead of HashSet.

Answer (score -1):

Here is example in javascript, but it can be easily rewritten to java using any kind of dictionary/map.

```js
people = new Map()
user = {id:"das", name: "Darek"}
people.set(user.id, user)
user = {id:"aaa", name: "Czarrek"}
people.set(user.id, user)
user = {id:"bbb", name: "Marek"}
people.set(user.id, user)

console.log(people.get("das"), people.get("aaa"), people.get("bbb"), people.size);

people.delete('aaa');

console.log(people.get("das"), people.get("aaa"), people.get("bbb"), people.size);
```

Map add works in O(1) (for hashmaps), removal is also in O(1). If data structure you chosen to use in your language is implemented using some king of trees then both operations runs in O(log(n)) (probably).

If have bare randomly sorted List and no additional data then only options is to look through all list's items. And it cannot be done faster than O(n)

You should use Map/Hashmap/Dictionary(doesn't matter how they are called in your language), from the very beginning if you want to be able to pick/remove items fast(ie. O(log n) or better)).

Comment: OP is interested in a java solution not javascript. Also this post isn't tagged for javascript so why confuse people by posting irrelevant codes?

Comment: General rules of computer programming are the same everywhere. and language doesn't matter. Computational complexity and clever use of data structures is what is important. I can rewrite almost any code from java, c++,c#, python to JS when there is idea(algorithm) behind it. I always hoped it works both ways, and my answer would be helpful.

Comment: Do you think OP will be able to write the java code based upon your javascript codes? I don't think so. OP already knew that logically a particular entry could be removed in a better way other than iterating all entries (which is why he made this post) but he didn't knew how to do it in java. Also, in your solution, map is really not required. Plus you haven't addressed OP's sorting need based on date of creation.